# Order by clause confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below are the contents of sid column in a table ( where "S05201215" is
a fixed string and remaining part of the Sring is a sequence of
numbers)

```
S052012151 
S052012152 
S052012153 
S052012154
S052012155
S052012156
```

I want to sort the the remaining part of the string (i.e.
the numbers that i've appended to the string `S05201215`  in
descending order ..  what modifications should i do to the below query
to get desired output?

```
SELECT `sid` FROM `mytable` order by SUBSTRING(`sid`,10,length(`sid`))
```

Comment: You need to convert substring to int to use numerical sort. List of 1, 10, 2 will be sorted by your current query as 1, 10, 2, and if you convert it to int 1, 2, 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort in descending order, just add "DESC" to the end of your ORDER BY:

```
SELECT `sid`
FROM `mytable`
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(`sid`, 10, length(`sid`)) DESC
```

However, if the values of sid are of different lengths, you are probably going to want to cast the values to a numeric type before sorting:

```
SELECT `sid`
FROM `mytable`
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(`sid`, 10, length(`sid`)) AS SIGNED) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT `sid` FROM `mytable` order by SUBSTRING(`sid`,10,length(`sid`)) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (assumptions are bad) the string remains the same length **ALL THE TIME**, just do a simple `order by sid`

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your data, but maybe something like this:

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING(sid, 0, 10) AS prefix, SUBSTRING(sid, 11) AS suffix
    FROM mytable
ORDER BY suffix
```

It look suspiciously like you're trying to implement your own little database *inside* the database, though, which is something you should avoid at all cost - let the database do what it's good at and normalize your model.